# Rails user login, only garant access to pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a rails application and written a simple login script.

Login checks if the entered password is the same like the hashed one in database.

Then I save the user ID into Session.

Now I want that pages are only vissible or only can be access if a user is loged in ..

How can I do achieve this?

thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't do this myself when gems like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) could do that for me in the matter of minutes.

Although, If you really do want to do this yourself, I would do a `user_logged_in!` method in your `ApplicationController` that would be called before every action (you can choose which action should be checked with `before_action`):

```
class ApplicationController < BaseController
  before_action :user_logged_in!

  protected

  def user_logged_in!
    # Logic that checks if the user is actually logged in (check in session, etc).

    # If not logged in, redirect the user to the root page with a flash message.
  end
end
```

For the actions/controllers where the user does not need to be authenticated, you can use `skip_before_action`:

```
class DomainsController < BaseController
  skip_before_action :user_logged_in!, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

Comment: yeah but thats not the solution. when I'm not logged in I can call domain/users/edit ...

but that should only be possible after a user is logged in ..

Comment: Absolutely. Then, in your `domains_controller` for instance, you would be able to skip this validation by using `skip_before_action`. I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: and thanks for the hint with device. I knew the gem. But I only need minimal function and I want to do It "by my selve" ;)

Comment: the skip_before_action can I define this globally? so that each controller automatically got this line of code?

Comment: I'd say so. You could try to put this in the `ApplicationController`, so that all the subclasses with the `index` and `show` actions will not enforce a user to be logged in.